# Angular RxJS - guard doesn't see updated value of observable in service

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, reactive

I have an 'onboarding' page, that should be filled by the user once, and set the "passedOnboarding" flag to 'true' in the db.

After submitting the form, it should redirect the user to his dashboard page.

The 'dashboard' page is behind a guard that makes sure the user filled the onboarding form, and redirects him back there if he didn't.

I have an `accountDetails$` observable, which looks like that:

```
refreshAccountDetails$ = new BehaviorSubject <void> (null);

accountDetails$ = this.refreshAccountDetails$.pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap(() => this.getAccountDetails()),
    shareReplay());
```

the `refreshAccountDetails$` behaviorSubject is the source of the stream, in order to allow refreshing the accountDetails$ from the server if needed.

This is onboarding submit function:

```
submitForm() {
    this.userService.accountDetails$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(accountDetails => {
      const submitModel = ... 
      this.userService.onboarding(submitModel)
        .subscribe(() => {
          this.router.navigateByUrl(dashboard_path);
        });
    });
  }
```

The following is the onboarding function, and you can see the after the form is submitted, I attempt to trigger a refresh of the `accountDetails$`,
  so that the guard will 'see' the updated details, and allow the navigation to the 'dashboard':

```
onboarding(request: OnboardingRequest): Observable<ClientDetailsResponse> {
    return this.http.postTyped<ClientDetailsResponse>(this.ONBOARDING_ENDPOINT, request).pipe(
      tap(() => {
        this.refreshAccountDetails$.next(null);
      })
    );
  }
```

And the guard that i set on the dashboard is :

```
export class OnboardingRequiredGuard implements CanActivate {
    canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        return this.userService.accountDetails$.pipe(
          map(accountDetails => {
            if (!accountDetails.isOnboardingFilled) {
              return this.router.parseUrl(_OnboardingPath_);
            }
            return true;
          })
        );
      }
    }
```

The problem is that the guard 'sees' the old value, where the flag is not set, so it redirects back to the onboarding page.

I'm not sure if the `accountDetail$` observable and it's source are set correctly, or if something else is wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: `canActivate` has to return a boolean, maybe you just need to force cast `this.router.parseUrl(_OnboardingPath_)` ?, something like `this.router.parseUrl(_OnboardingPath_) ? true | false` ?

Comment: @Motassem in latest versions of angular you can also return other types, such as Observable<boolean>, Promises, and what I used, UrlTree. If you return a UrlTree, it will redirect to that url. There is a priority mechanism in case multiple guards return a UrlTree. (parseUrl is a function that takes a string and converts it to a UrlTree) Very useful!

Comment: My comment has nothing to do with your problem however I'd like to point out that subscribing in another subscription is not a great situation. You should take a look at mergeMap and switchMap. Using these RxJS operators you can reduce the submitForm method to only one subscription. ;)

Comment: Thanks @Ruben I somehow didn't notice that.. I know about switchMap and mergeMap.

Comment: have you figured it out at the end?

Comment: Yes, i changed the refreshAccountDetails$ = new BehaviorSubject<void>(); to now contain the actual account details, and instead of  just nexting it, and fetching the updated details elsewhere, i now submit the onboarding, switchMap to fetch the updated account details from the server, and nexting the BehaviorSubject with the update account details. Now the guard sees the correct data. Not sure if that's the best way of doing it, but it works for me.